# Finding the average time of pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a panda that has the following format:

```
title   |   decision   |   Time submitted
Book1   |      1       |   1486507594
Book1   |      2       |   1485450353
```

What I would like to do is find the average time of submission for books with decision = 1 and then average submission time for books with decision = 2. I have tried using:

```
df_avg.loc[df_avg['decision'] == 2, 'submitted'].sum()
df_avg.loc[df_avg['decision'] == 1, 'submitted'].sum()
```

but it does not work for times. I even tried doing the above before and after converting the times to the date and time using datetime. Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can convert datetime to `ns` unix format first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
print (df_avg)
   title  decision  Time submitted
0  Book1         1      1486507594
1  Book1         1      1486500012
2  Book1         2      1485480353
3  Book1         2      1485450353

df_avg['Time submitted'] = pd.to_datetime(df_avg['Time submitted'], unit='s')
                             .values.astype(np.int64)

df = df_avg.groupby('decision', as_index=False)['Time submitted'].mean()
df['Time submitted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time submitted'], unit='ns')
print (df)
   decision      Time submitted
0         1 2017-02-07 21:43:23
1         2 2017-01-26 21:15:53
```

But for you data also works multiple `second`s unix data to `10**9`:

```
df = (df_avg['Time submitted'] * 10**9).groupby(df_avg['decision']).mean().reset_index()
df['Time submitted'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time submitted'], unit='ns')
print (df)
   decision      Time submitted
0         1 2017-02-07 21:43:23
1         2 2017-01-26 21:15:53
```