# Find the average time in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a single column of time stamp data for which I would like to find the average.

```
In [70]:temp
Out[70]: 
0       2018-01-31 11:42:14
1       2018-01-05 15:58:37
2       2018-01-05 10:18:49
3       2018-01-30 13:53:49
4       2018-01-03 14:36:20
5       2018-01-03 11:58:43
Name: tradeDateTime, Length: 15150, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In general, my expected output should be the average of this column. I tried `pd.to_datetime` and other techniques involving `mean` but couldn't get a result.

I'm supposing a `groupby` is in order first by the date (01-01-2018 - 31-01-2018) and then find the mean in each day and average those?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the average time of pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804285/finding-the-average-time-of-pandas-column)

Comment: What does "average time and date" mean? How can you average absolute times? What is the mean of `2018-01-03 14:36:20` and `2018-01-03 11:58:43`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the average time of pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804285/finding-the-average-time-of-pandas-column)

Comment: @DeepSpace between these times I see a 02:37:37 interval. Then I have to find the next interval, etc and average those intervals.