# Pandas group and average over time

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```py
                    t  val
0 2022-01-01 10:00:00    1
1 2022-01-02 10:00:00    1
2 2022-01-03 10:00:00    1
3 2022-01-04 10:00:00    1
4 2022-01-05 10:00:00    1
5 2022-01-06 10:00:00    2
6 2022-01-07 10:00:00    2
7 2022-01-08 10:00:00    2
8 2022-01-09 10:00:00    2
9 2022-01-10 10:00:00    2
```

It is possible to compute the mean over the a datetime column:

```py
df["t"].mean()
```

However, if I try to group the dataset by `val` and compute the mean over the `t` column:

```
df.groupby("val")["t"].mean()
```

an error appears:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

So direct aggregation does not work. A workaround is to convert first `t` to POSIX timestamp and then convert the grouped column back to datetime, as shown in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804285/finding-the-average-time-of-pandas-column):

```py
df["tstamp"] = df["t"].astype(int)
gr = df.groupby("val")["tstamp"].mean()
dfres = pd.to_datetime(gr)
```

Is there any more elegant way (using a one-liner) to achieve aggregation over time without its explicit conversion?

Comment: If your column already contains `pd.Timestamp` instances, you don't need to apply any transformation. Now, if your values are strings, you should probably convert your column as datetime. Can you show us your dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358564/computing-the-mean-for-python-datetime):

```
df.groupby('val')['t'].apply(lambda x: x.min() + (x - x.min()).mean())

Output:

val
1   2022-01-03 10:00:00
2   2022-01-08 10:00:00
```